# Pypy does not find Flask on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, pip, pypy

I am running a `flask` server on `buster` `raspbian` on my Raspberry Pi Zero W microcomputer.  I am not using any environments and I am running my server by command

```
sudo python www.py
```

The server is working fine but is a bit slow.  So my idea was to use `pypy` instead of `python`.  However, `pypy` returns error

```
ImportError: No module named flask
```

I have tried all possible options to instal `flask` (`sudo pip install flask`, `sudo pip3 install flask`) to no avail.

Do you have any suggestion what to do?

The information that this simply cannot be done would also be useful, so I can move on finding other (working) solutions.

Comment: try: "pip install -U Flask" and then when u call it "from flask import Flask"

Comment: @Carlo1585 `Requirement already up-to-date: flask in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (1.0.2)˙

Answer (score 0):

The standard system commands to install Python stuff always install it for CPython specifically, not PyPy.

Try:

```
sudo pypy -m ensurepip

sudo pypy -m pip install flask
```

Comment: `ensurepip is disabled in Debian/Ubuntu for the system python.`

`/usr/bin/pypy: No module named pip`